# Can't get Magento javascript component to initialize before my phtml script

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm trying to call a Magento Javascript Component in my phtml page to get the customer data saved in session.

I'm having an issue in that the customerdata constructor gets loaded after my script and I can't figure out how to get my script to run after.

This is the customer-data.js file that needs to get loaded before my script

```
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data': function (settings) {
            options = settings;
            invalidateCacheBySessionTimeOut(settings);
            invalidateCacheByCloseCookieSession();
            customerData.init();
 }
```

Here is how I'm trying to call it

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'domReady!',
    'mage/loader'
], function (jQuery,customerData) {
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var data = customerData.get('mysession-data');


    });
});
```

My code works when the customerdata gets initialized but it's not always getting initialized first.

Is there anyway to configure this to get the customerdata to initialize and then I can call my session data?

Comment: have you find a way to resolve this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use RequireJs mixins in order to hook the core function.

```
var config = {
    'config':{
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data': {
                'Vendor_Module/hook.js':true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Alan Storm described it here : http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

You can try to use shim option with requirejs as explain here :

[Requirejs shim option not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102113/requirejs-shim-option-not-working)

Comment: thanks. I don't really want to alter an existing function. I just want to get the content of customerData after it's initialized. I think the script that runs the "text/x-magento-init" must happen after my code

Comment: Do you try shim option ? The jQuery ready is not require I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in

```
// Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

This basically tells magento to load Magento_Customer module first before running your module, so by then customer-data will be available.